# Handle REST API timeout in time consuming operations

Tags: rest

How is possible to handle timeouts in time consuming operations in a REST API. Let's say we have the following scenario as example:

1. A client service sends a request to insert a resource through a REST API.
2. Timeout elapses. The client thinks the insertion failed.
3. REST API keep working and finishes the insertion.
4. Client do not notify the resource insertion and it status is "Failed".

I can think I a solution with a message broker to send orders to a queue and wait until they are solved.

Any other workaround?

EDIT 1:

- [POST-PUT Pattern](http://restalk-patterns.org/post-put.html) as has been suggested in this thread.
- A Message Broker (add more complexity to the system)
- [Callback or webhook](https://dzone.com/articles/rest-callbacks). Pass in the request a return url that the server API can call to let the client know that the work is completed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTTP offers a [set of properties](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2) for invoking certain methods. These are primarily `safetiness`, `idempotency` and `cacheability`. While the first one guarantees a client that no data is modified, the 2nd one gives a promise whether a request can be reissued in regards to connection issues and the client not knowing whether the initial request succeeded or not and only the response got lost mid way. `PUT` i.e. does provide such a property, i.e.

A simple `POST` request to "insert" some data does not have any of these properties. A server receiving a `POST` request furthermore processes the payload according to its own semantics. The client does not know beforehand whether a resource will be created or if the server just ignores the request. In case the server created a resource the server will inform the client via the `Location` HTTP response header pointing to the actual location the client can retrieve information from.

`PUT` is usually used only to "update" a resource, though according to [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) it can also be used in order to create a new resource if it does not yet exist. As with `POST` on a successful resource creation the `PUT` response should include such a `Location` HTTP response header to inform the client that a resource was created.

The [POST-PUT-Creation pattern](http://restalk-patterns.org/post-put.html) separates the creation of the URI from the actual persistence of the representation by first firing off `POST` requests to the server until a response is received containing a `Location` HTTP response header. This header is used in a `PUT` request to actually send the payload to the server. As `PUT` is idempotent the server simply can reissue the request until it receives a valid response from the server.

On sending the initial `POST` request to the server, a client can't be sure whether the request reached the server and only the response got lost, or the initial request didn't make it to the server. As the request is only used to create a new URI (without any content yet) the client may simply reissue the request and in worst case just create a new URI that points to nothing. The server may have a cleanup routine that frees unused URIs after a certain amount of time.

Once the client receives the URI, it simply can use `PUT` to reliably send data to the server. As long as the client didn't receive a valid response, it can just reissue the request over and over until it receives a response.

I therefore do not see the need to use a message-oriented middleware (MOM) using brokers and queues in order to guarantee reliable messaging.

Comment: Nice post, based in the idempotency of the PUT we can send as many as needed, once the resource was partially created with the POST. If we get a timeout the client just need to send another PUT. Definitely that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could also cache the data after a successful insertion with a previously exchanged request_id or something of that sort. But I believe message broker with some asynchronous task runner is a much better way to deal with the problem especially if your request thread is a scarce resource. What I mean by that is. If you are receiving a good amount of requests all the time. Then it is a good idea to keep your responses as quickly as possible so the workers will be available for any requests to come.